# Foreach em PHP com SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, foreach

Preciso ter acesso as informações (id_midia, midia_tipo, etc) dentro do array de objetos abaixo.
Como devo proceder?

```
 [midias] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [midia] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                            (
                                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id_midia] => abcdef
                                                        [ds_midia_credi] => gggggg
                                                        [ds_midia] => aaaaaaaa
                                                        [nm_midia_inter] => imagem_01.jpg
                                                        [midia_link] => http://portal.teste///_midias/jpg/2018/02/07/imagem_01.jpg
                                                        [midia_tipo] => 2
                                                    )

                                                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                    (
                                                        [id_midia] => abcdef
                                                        [ds_midia_credi] => gggggg
                                                        [ds_midia] => aaaaaaaa
                                                        [nm_midia_inter] => video_01.jpg
                                                        [midia_link] => http://portal.teste///_midias/jpg/2018/03/07/video_01.mpg
                                                        [midia_tipo] => 4
                                                    )
```

Comment: O código/xml que tens para gerar essa estrutura é util também, edita coloca pff

Comment: Para gerar essa estrutura eu dou um print_r($resultados);

Comment: @DiegoAlbuquerque O Miguel quis dizer o código que gera o conteúdo de `$resultado`.

Comment: foreach($midias->mídia as $key => $dados){ echo $dados->id_midia}